# Discord Bot ERROR "MaxListenersExceededWarning"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Would mean a lot if someone could help. Been trying to fix this for ages.
Do you guys think there is a possibility to fix it?

```
C:\Users\WFMod\Desktop\CTZY Bot>node .
    (node:11384) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 message listeners added to [Client]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
    Bot is online.
    C:\Users\WFMod\Desktop\CTZY Bot\index.js:789       
                const ghembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                                ^

    TypeError: Discord.RichEmbed is not a constructor
        at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\WFMod\Desktop\CTZY Bot\index.js:789:29)
        at Client.emit (events.js:326:22)
        at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\WFMod\Desktop\CTZY Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
        at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\WFMod\Desktop\CTZY Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
        at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\WFMod\Desktop\CTZY Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
        at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\WFMod\Desktop\CTZY Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
        at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\WFMod\Desktop\CTZY Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
        at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\WFMod\Desktop\CTZY Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
        at WebSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
        at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\WFMod\Desktop\CTZY Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:825:20)

    C:\Users\WFMod\Desktop\CTZY Bot>
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, `Discord.RichEmbed` is no longer a constructor as of Discord JS v12. Use `Discord.MessageEmbed`.

---

```js
const ghembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that in v14 you have to use Discord.EmbedBuilder instead :)